# Permission denied when cloning project

Tags: git, powershell, ssh, windows-10

I am attempting to clone an existing project from Bitbucket onto my Windows work station.

**I have generated my keys** using ssh-keygen in Windows Powershell and saved to `~/.ssh`. **I added my pub key** to my Bitbucket account. I use `ssh -T git@bitbucket.org` to **verify that I can login** and it is certainly using my account.

My project leader has verified backwards and forwards that **I have full permissions** to this project. I have pulled from and pushed to it from other work stations.

But cloning the project onto this computer returns `Permission denied (publickey). Fatal: Could not read from remote repository.`

I run `ssh -Tv git@bitbucket.org` and verified that it is using my correct public key. We're at a loss about what could be causing this permission issue.

Comment: Are you 100% sure git uses the correct key?

Comment: I have verified via the `ssh -T git@bitbucket.org` command that my proper key is being used. The key file has a distinct name.

Comment: Your `ssh` step does  not prove that `git clone` uses the same key because it could call `ssh` in a complete different way... So you need to doubl check both git and ssh configuration. When you are sure it is the correct key, then you know it is no more an ssh problem but something else.

Comment: Noted. How do you advise I verify the key being used by git?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLVED!**

My config file in the `~\.ssh` directory was not correct. I was unfamiliar with how this file was suppose to be structured. It was configured for Github instead of Bitbucket and was not properly indented. This post was helpful.
https://superuser.com/a/232406

After fixing this, I tried to clone again and it through a new error. `Invalid repository syntax`. I removed `ssh://` from the repository path and tried it as Bitbucket instructs. Cloning succeeded.

Comment: "in order to avoid any ~/.ssh/config interference.": that is what I was saying!

Comment: You recommended using the ssh:// syntax, which did nothing to resolve the error. Once I fixed the config file (rather than avoid it), using this syntax caused a new error. It wasn't until I removed the protocol that the clone worked. I'm sorry, but your advice was consistently wrong here.